# passing data to all component | angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, multidimensional-array

I have component has array and I want to pass this object to all other components.
in my component I have a function gets the data based on the cookie value then I want to put the object data in other components {{lang.data1}}.

```
    this.lang=this._webService.getlang(this.cookieValue);
```

how can I use lang in all other component.

Comment: Have you tried using a shared service ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) and inject language service or you can you BaseComponent

```
export class BaseComponent {

    public language: any;

    constructor() {
        this.language = configuration.language;
    }
}
export class BlockComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.language);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the component with array as a service. Initialize that service in the root component and import that service array at any component you want.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a Small to medium Scale application

then you make you services inorder to pass information to all the components using Event Emitters

But if this is for a large application i would recommend you to user ngrx i:e redux approach where all the data is stored at a particular location.

If you want to check how redux works please look at this repo in git hub has a very simple demo on ngrx store with angular.

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts